# Time/duration format `PT12H30M` from a .NET web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, datetime-format

I am getting a time/duration from a .NET web service in this format: `PT12H30M` How can this be handled?

Below is the Xml i'm getting from webservice

```
<a:Date>2013-01-09T00:00:00</a:Date> 
<a:StartTime>PT11H30M</a:StartTime> 
<a:EndTime>PT12H</a:EndTime>
```

I just want to convert it to standard C# DateTime format. Could anybody please help me with this?

Note : I have parsed the xml... and now i have both the value, but how to convert?

Comment: It's odd to specify a *time of day* as a period like that...

Comment: Hey jon, Somebody has created service, I just have access to consume it. I can't change the webservice. Do u have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, it's odd to specify a time of day like that (and it's also odd to specify a date as a date/time), but [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) handles periods like that:

```
LocalDateTimePattern dateTimePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern;
LocalDateTime date = dateTimePattern.Parse(dateText).Value;

PeriodPattern pattern = PeriodPattern.RoundtripPattern;
Period startTime = pattern.Parse(startTimeText).Value;
Period endTime = pattern.Parse(endTimeText).Value;

LocalDateTime startDateTime = date + startTime;
LocalDateTime endDateTime = date + endTime;
```

You *could* convert that into a BCL `DateTime` value afterwards if you really wanted to, but I'd encourage you to just use Noda Time throughout your app, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

The notation

```
<a:StartTime>PT11H30M</a:StartTime> 
<a:EndTime>PT12H</a:EndTime>
```

corresponds to the dayTimeDuration (based on the duration dataype) specified in datatypes.xsd - have a look [here](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dayTimeDuration.html) for clarification.

```
P = duration marker
nD = optional unsigned integer corresponding to number of days
T = date time separator
nH = number of hours
```

and so on - you get the idea :)

So to parse it you could do something like the quick & dirty example below:

```
 var xmla = @"
<root xmlns:a=""a"">
<a:Date>2013-01-09T00:00:00</a:Date> 
<a:StartTime>PT11H30M</a:StartTime> 
<a:EndTime>PT12H</a:EndTime> 
</root>";
    var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    ns.AddNamespace("a", "a");
    var ele = XElement.Parse(xmla);
    var start = ele.XPathSelectElement("//a:StartTime", ns);
    var end = ele.XPathSelectElement("//a:EndTime", ns);
    var startTime = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(start.Value);
    var endTime = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(end.Value);
    var date = ele.XPathSelectElement("//a:Date", ns);
    var dateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(date.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);

    Console.WriteLine("Ran at {0} for a duration of  {1}", dateTime + startTime, endTime - startTime);
```